# Convert specific column of file into upper case in unix (without using awk and sed)

Tags: unix

My file is as below 
file name = test

```
1    abc
2    xyz
3    pqr
```

How can i convert second column of file in upper case without using awk or sed.

Comment: why don't use awk? it would be the best for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022529/how-can-i-change-a-certain-field-of-a-file-into-upper-case-using-awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tr` to transform from lowercase to uppercase. `cut` will extract the single columns and `paste` will combine the separated columns again.

Assumption: Columns are delimited by tabs.

```
paste <(cut -f1 file) <(cut -f2 file | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

Replace `file` with your file name (that is `test` in your case).

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for an answer to not change the delimiter in output.  This works fine!

Answer (score 2):

In pure `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r col1 col2;
do
    printf "%s%7s\n" "$col1" "${col2^^}"

done < file > output-file
```

Input-file

```
$ cat file
1    abc
2    xyz
3    pqr
```

Output-file

```
$ cat output-file
1    ABC
2    XYZ
3    PQR
```