# Transforming a field in a csv file and resaving to another file with bash

Tags: bash, csv, tr

I apologize in advance if this seems like a simple question. However, I am a beginner in bash commands and scripting, so I hope you all understand why I am not able to solve this on my own.

What I want to achieve is to change the values in one field of a csv file to uppercase, and then resave the csv file with the transformed field and all the other fields included, each retaining their index.

For instance, I have this csv:

```
1,Jun 4 2021,car,4856
2,Jul 31 2021,car,4154
3,Aug 14 2021,bus,4070
4,Aug 2 2021,car,4095
```

I want to transform the third field that holds the vehicle type into uppercase - CAR, BUS, etc. and then resave the csv file with the transformed field.

I have tried using the 'tr' command thus:

```
cut -d"," -f4 data.csv | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

This takes the field and does the transformation. But how do I paste and replace the column in the csv file?
It did not work because the field argument cannot be passed into the tr command.

Comment: You say you want to transform the 3rd field but you also say `cut -d"," -f4 data.csv` (note - selecting the **4th** field) works, please explain or fix that. Also, clarify what `each retaining their index` means.

Comment: @Ed Morton, That was a typo from my end. `-f4` should be `-f3`. Apologies. What I am trying to do is to transform the third field in the input csv file named data.csv into uppercase, then resave the csv file with another name. I hope that gives more clarity

Comment: No problem, please just [edit] your question to fix that and explain what `each retaining their index` means or remove that statement if it's meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

A `gnu sed` solution:

```sh
sed -i -E 's/^(([^,]+,){2})([^,]+)/\1\U\3/' file.csv

cat file

1,Jun 4 2021,CAR,4856
2,Jul 31 2021,CAR,4154
3,Aug 14 2021,BUS,4070
4,Aug 2 2021,CAR,4095
```

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `(([^,]+,){2})`: Match first 2 fields and capture them in group #1
- `([^,]+)`: Match 3rd field and capture it in group #3
- `\1`: Put capture value of group #1 back in replacement
- `\U\3`: Put uppercase capture value of group #3 back in replacement

Or a `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$3 = toupper($3)} 1' file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. The awk solution does not seem to work on my system. It says -i is not an option. The sed solution works normally, however, it failed when I added it to my Airflow DAG file. Submission failed. It reported some syntax (Unicode) error. I think the issue was with the fields selection {2}. It was trying to read it as bytes even when the whole bash command has been correctly quoted into a string. What do you think I can do? Is there any way to bypass this hurdle? Perhaps, a modification to the sed command?

Comment: That's why it says that you need GNU Awk specifically. With a regular Awk, you can remove the `-i inplace` and save the output to a temporary file, then move it back on top of the original file.

Comment: As @tripleee has rightly suggested you can use: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$3 = toupper($3)} 1' file.csv > _out && mv _out file.csv` to get it working in any non-gnu `awk`. I have no idea about the `Airflow DAG file`. `gnu sed` command works fine on any terminal or in any shell script.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=","} {$3=toupper($3)} {print}' file
```

Output to file:

```
1,Jun 4 2021,CAR,4856
2,Jul 31 2021,CAR,4154
3,Aug 14 2021,BUS,4070
4,Aug 2 2021,CAR,4095
```

See: [How can I change a certain field of a file into upper-case using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14022529/3776858), [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/3776858) and [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `cut` and `tr`, you need to add `paste` to the mix.

```
SEP=","
IN="data.csv"

paste -d$SEP \
  <( <$IN cut -d$SEP -f1,2 ) \
  <( <$IN cut -d$SEP -f3 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' ) \
  <( <$IN cut -d$SEP -f4 )
```

I did factor out the repeating things - separator and input file - into variables `SEP` and `IN` respectively.

How it all works:

- get the untransformed columns before #3
- get col #3 and transform it with `tr`
- get the remaining columns
- `paste` it all together, line by line
- the need for intermediate files is avoided by using shell substitution

Downsides:

- the data seems to be read 3 times, but disk cache will help a lot
- the data is parsed 3 times, for sure (by `cut`)
- but unless your input is a few gigabytes, this does not matter